# Adding gesture recognizer control to JTRevealSideBarDemoV2

Tags: ios

I am using JTRevealSideBarDemoV2 for the implementation of the side panels like facebook and Path application. I have configured it in every sense and just want to add one more feature into this library. What I want is to apply gesture recognizer control in this library just similar to facebook. can somebody help?

The link for downloading this library is:-https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jtrevealsidebar

Thanks!

@wattson:- this is the code which I have added for implementing Gesture Recognizer. BBut it is behaving very abnormally. If you have downloaded the code for JTRevealSideBarDemoV2 then you can analyze the code which i have written for.

The code is:

```
        (void)setUpGestures{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(movePanel:)];
   [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];

      [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
      }

     -(void)movePanel:(id)sender {
        [[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

         CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
        translationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:[sender view]];

       if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //UIView *childView = nil;

    if(velocity.x > 0) {
        if (!JTRevealedStateRight) {
             [self revealLeftSidebar:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender];
        }
    } else {
        if (!JTRevealedStateLeft) {
             [self revealRightSidebar:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender];
        }

    }
    // Make sure the view you're working with is front and center.
    //[self.view sendSubviewToBack:];
    [[sender view] bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
}

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    if(velocity.x > 0) {
        // NSLog(@"gesture went right");
    } else {
        // NSLog(@"gesture went left");
    }

    if (!_showPanel) {
        [self revealLeftSidebar:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender];
    } else {
        if (JTRevealedStateLeft) {
            [self revealRightSidebar:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender];
        }  else if (JTRevealedStateRight) {
            [self revealLeftSidebar:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender];
        }
    }
}

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    if(velocity.x > 0) {
        // NSLog(@"gesture went right");
    } else {
        // NSLog(@"gesture went left");
    }

    // Are you more than halfway? If so, show the panel when done dragging by setting this
      value to YES (1).
    _showPanel = abs([sender view].center.x - self.view.frame.size.width/2) > 
      self.view.frame.size.width/2;

    // Allow dragging only in x-coordinates by only updating the x-coordinate with
     translation position.
    [sender view].center = CGPointMake([sender view].center.x + translatedPoint.x, [sender
      view].center.y);
    [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];

    // If you needed to check for a change in direction, you could use this code to do so.
    if(velocity.x*_preVelocity.x + velocity.y*_preVelocity.y > 0) {
        // NSLog(@"same direction");
    } else {
        // NSLog(@"opposite direction");
    }

    _preVelocity = velocity;
}
```

}

Comment: i strongly recommend to use this demo for implementing Facebook sliding Feature. https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController  and read also how to use it. its very easy and not need to adding gesture separately.

Comment: but I didn't find it easy to apply in my project. So, If possible please suggest me how to implement the gesture recognizer in JTRevealSideBarDemoV2. Thanks!

Comment: post some code, how have you added the gesture and what part of it isn't working?

Comment: if you have the JTRevealSideBarDemoV2 code then I am posting what i have added in this class for Gesture Recognizer.:-

Comment: @wattson12: I have added the code in the main question asked. you can have a look at that.

Comment: what is abnormal about the behaviour?